# How can you "group" indices of certain multi-dimensional arrays to lower dimensional arrays (lower rank tensor)?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, tensor

So if i start with a tensor of rank 4 like $T_{ijkl}$. This is a 4-dimensional array with shape like = (U, V, W, X). Now for my specific problem I need to group the first and third index and the second and fourth index together, so that we get a 2-dimensional array or tensor of rank 2. It should look like $T_{ik};{jl}$. What is the fastest way to group these indices. Is there any numpy function for this? I want to avoid loops and constructing new arrays. In the future I'll also need to split indices so if you have any help for that that would also work.

I have already split tensors into higher rank tensors by just creating a new object of different size and dimensions and then fill in the values in a loop but this is not very clean code and inefficient I guess.

I'll try and give an example, but not to make it that hard  (too large to visualize), i'll go from a matrix (rank 2) to rank 1. This means you just group the two indices together

```
T = [[1,2,3], 
      [3,4,5]
      [7,8,9]]

unkownfunction(T, index1, index2) = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

But I want to be able to group indices of multidimensional tensors and by just appointing which indicies i want to group.

Comment: Add mcve - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example?

Comment: `np.swapaxes(T, 2, 1)`, if I understand you correctly. An example of expected result would help a lot

Comment: Your mcve doesn't look like 4D.